# With an external wi-fi, the ping command gets 100% packet loss, but the internet works

Tags: networking, virtualbox, 20.04, internet, ping

For the network classes, I have bought the novel usb wi-fi adapter (Panda PAU09), and managed to connect to the internet in the VirtualBox, the Ubuntu OS 20.04. I could connect by my adapter, but I cannot get any results in the ping command neither by Windows, nor by Ubuntu, because it leads to the 100% packet loss. The paradox is that the internet works properly, so I can surf, execute "apt get" commands etc. How can it be solved?

P.S. I should add that I use the University's connection.

Comment: Is your guest OS getting the positive ping result?

Comment: I have written above, both gets negative results. The strange that the internet works in both, but pinging not.

Comment: What is your Network connection type on VirtualBox, NAT or Bridged Adapter?

Comment: Bridged Network with my laptop's WiFi. It is required to have it as this for future assignments.

Comment: Is it ping or DNS that's causing you issues (you note that you are on Uni network). `ping google.com` `ping 74.125.200.113` for me are same server.  If one that uses IP works and one that uses name does not,  it's DNS.  If this is case I recommend to switch to DNS over TLS so your Uni gateway doesn't intercept DNS. (I can give you steps for this)

Comment: @RobRaymond I cannot say, but I tried in my android phone, the same issue with ping. Maybe, it is the policy of the connection. What should be done in this case?

Comment: Do both a) `ping google.com` and b) `ping 74.125.200.113` fail?  Have you looked at imp packet loss?  Be a bit more expansive in you thinking and provision of context of your issue.  what about `resolvectl query google.com` ?

Comment: In Windows, both a) and b) gets "Request timed out" . In Linux (My android phone, Ubuntu VirtualBox), there is no message until I force-quit by Ctrl+C. In that case, I can see that all packets are lost. The case that not only google.com fails. But if I connect my external Wi-Fi adapter, there is 0% loss between IPs.